# What to write in CV about university degree unrelated to job

Tags: resume, applications

I am looking for front end development work, for which I have relevant experience to list. My degree is in politics.

Should I just write my degree, university and classification or should I expand on what I did there like my dissertation, modules, student newspaper stuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List degree, university and classification.

At some point in your life, you may be applying as a web developer for a political website or a news organization and your background in political science will come in handy. When that happens, you can expound on your background in political science in your cover letter.

Comment: Both question and answer are very broad. Yes, you should put your degree on, otherwise relevant information (that you have a degree) is missing. But don't expand on it, unless the job you are applying for has anything to do with politics.

Answer (score 6):

I have a degree in geology, but have never worked as a geologist.

Being a programming freelancer, I still list it - even though it seems less relevant than computer science or engineering would.

Apart from demonstrating that you have higher education, it can sometimes actually make your CV stand out from all the other more 'predictable' ones.